# Add specific values from the same mongoose collection - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created a collection in mongoose which looks like this:

```
 db.myservers.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5783a416c9"), "text_usage" : "15", "name" : "A1", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57831216c9"), "text_usage" : "220", "name" : "A2", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5783a41asd"), "text_usage" : "100", "name" : "A3", "__v" : 0 }
```

My schema work is like this:

```
var serverSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    text_usage: String
  })
var myServer = mongoose.model('MyServer', serverchema)
```

I want to add all the values in the text_usage together and divide by the number of objects in this list - so basically find an average. HOWEVER, my text_usage needs to be stored as a String as it comes from an API call, so would I have to parseString before adding the values together?

So the final results I want i s something like this:

```
var totalTextCount = 335;
var objectCount = 3;
var average = 111.66
```

I had a look at aggregate however I am only working with one collection so I dont think this is suitable for me? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can loop over the result of API call and calculate required fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate can't change existing datatype so in this case you should use find and iterate over all data's to get total, count and avg. like:

```
var totalTextCount = 0, average = 0, objectCount = 0;

MyServer.find().lean().exec(function(err, datas) {
  datas.forEach(function(data) {
    totalTextCount += parseInt(data.text_usage);
    objectCount+= 1;
  }); 

  average = totalTextCount / objectCount;
  console.log(totalTextCount, objectCount, average);
});
```

Comment: works like a charm... but what does the .lean().exec() do?

Comment: `.lean()` function will turn it into a normal JavaScript object and `.exec()` execute your query

Comment: Just to let you know, it works fine without lean and .exec :)

Comment: Yes, actually if you want to customize/edit data then you should use .lean() and instead of exec you can use callback function.

Answer (score 0):

first get the total  as follow

```
Model =db.model('ServerList', serverSchema);        
var userCount = serverModel.count('name');
```

then iterate over all record to find total

```
   var total =0;
 serverModel.find(function (err, servers) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
       servers.forEach(function(server){
       total += parseInt(server.text_usage);
       });
 })
```

Comment: what the index for?